# How to get difference month from 2 date PHP?

Tags: php, date, date-math

i have date

```
$d1='2014-02-01';
$d2='2013-11-01';
```

i want if i minus `$d2 - $d1 = i get difference of month = -3` and if `$d1 - $d2 = 3` ,

Any one can help, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

```
$d1= new DateTime('2014-02-01');
$d2= new DateTime('2013-11-01');
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
echo $diff->format("%r%m");
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5wiWnT)

Comment: I went with lowercase r as I don't think they want thew `+` sign when the diff is positive

Comment: but if $diff=$d2->diff($d1); the result isn't -3

Comment: The date math may work backwards of how you are expecting. But that is easily worked around by switching the operands: `$diff=$d1->diff($d2);` The results will be consistent.